# MySQL Workbench can only connect to localhost:3306

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently running MySQL Workbench on Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 18.04). When I connect to localhost:3306 using root access it connects to MySQL Server but when I try to connect to other ports (Specifically Port 3307 since my professor is requiring us to use Port 3307), I cannot seem to connect.

Comment: change in the my.cnf or ini file of the server the port to 3307 and restart mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps-

- Open **my.cnf** file:

  `# vi /etc/my.cnf`
- Set new port 3307:

  `port=3307`
- Save and close the file. Then restart mysqld

  `# service mysqld restart`